# What does the colon before the name mean in this JSON like string?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, json

I encountered this string that looks like JSON syntax but I've never seen a property with a colon before it and not with a backwards greater than or equals sign:

```
Badge {
    :id=>36, 
    :name=>"Appreciated", 
    :default_icon=>"fa-heart", 
    :badge_type_id=>3, 
    :query=>"", 
    :default_badge_grouping_id=>2, 
    :trigger=>0, 
    :auto_revoke=>false, 
    :system=>true
}
```

Is it a JSON string and if so what does the colon do?

Comment: I think that's Ruby. Where did you find the code?

Comment: It was output to the console during an upgrade of Discourse

Comment: https://github.com/discourse/discourse ... Discourse is about 65% ruby by weight (according to GitHub).

Comment: `Badge` is the name of the class. I updated my answer with a link to the file that defines the class. The hash literal is valid Ruby, but a human would be more likely to use the `key: value` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

Knowing more about the context (message written to console during an updgrade of discourse), you likely saw an instance of [this class](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/95f263995d898fd47a578c972bd1fa51098ace58/app/models/badge.rb) being printed.

---

I think you are looking at Ruby code, although it is strange to mix symbol literals and `=>`.

- An identifier beginning with a colon is a `:symbol` literal.
- A key-value pair in a hash table can be written `key => value` or `key: value`, but the latter syntax only works with symbol literals.
- `Badge` doesn't have parentheses after it and you can omit parentheses.

Some other languages use `=>` to separate key value pairs, here's why the other likely suspects don't fit.

- Perl: A key begining with `:` must be quoted. Bare identifiers and bare identifiers with a leading `-` are the only things that do not need to be quoted in Perl in this context.
- PHP: PHP allows `{}` for accessing array values `$a{6}`, but does not allow braces for array literals. Also, you can't leave the parentheses off a function call in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Colon variable refers to :abc type variables you might have seen in Ruby.
They are called Ruby symbols.

A Ruby symbol is not a variable because it cannot be assigned a value.

Also, a Ruby symbol is not a reference to another variable nor is it a pointer to a memory location.

Still a symbol has a value and whenever the name of the symbol is same, its value is the same.

An example will make it more clear.

```
# It is trivial to assign a value to a variable.
abc = "1"
=> "1"

# But a symbol cannot be assigned any value.
:a = "1"
# SyntaxError: A symbol cannot be assigned a value

# Can use a variable as a map-key 
m = {abc => "1"}
=> {"1"=>"1"}

# Can use a string as a map-key 
=> {"def"=>"1"}

# Can also use a symbol as a map-key 
m = {:a => "1"}
=> {:a=>"1"}

# Can use same symbol as key in another map
m2 = {:a => "2"}
=> {:a=>"2"}

# And it won't affect the previous map.
m
=> {:a=>"1"}

m2
=> {:a=>"2"}
```

Comment: So is a symbol comparable to a constant?

Comment: No, a symbol in Ruby is comparable to a symbol in Lisp or in Scala. A Ruby symbol is a datatype that represents the concept of a "name" or a "label", just like a Ruby string represents the concept of "text" or a Ruby integer represents the concept of, well, "integer".